# Root user is not able to paste files into nonroot user's home directoy

Tags: linux, permissions, redhat

Hello Friends,
               I am using rhel 5.3. First of all I want to discuss what I did earlier. I was using this system(200.0.0.15) as NIS Client. So I had started autofs service and had shared servers home directory (200.0.0.1) on client.

Now I am on client at 200.0.0.15 and will discuss everything of this machine only every time when I tried to add a new user with useradd command, it gave error that the new directory of newusername can not be created under /home/. I did some googling and found I have to stop autofs service. I did same and for every new user a new directory is created automatically under /home.

But now the problem is that I am not able to paste any files into the directory /home/newuser. It gives the error "permisison denied" even when I try as root user to copy data into it. It is only allowing empty directories to be pasted into it.
Because of this problem I am not able to upload or download any file to or from this system or ssh server.

Kindly suggest what I can do. How can root user paste data into its non-root user's home directory? Please suggest me

Comment: Friend any suggestion plz

Answer (score 0):

By default the user root on NFS is mapped to the user nobody for security reasons.